# How to make XP install ubuntu from USB?

Tags: windows-xp, installation, usb, ubuntu-9.10

I want to install ubuntu on my PC which is running windows XP right now. I have made my pen drive bootable and have loaded Ubuntu on it. When I insert the pen drive at the time of booting of my PC, nothing happens and windows XP starts normally instead of asking me if I want to boot from my pen drive. Also when, I entered my BIOS setting to change the boot order there was no option of pen drive as a boot device.

Please suggest me a way to install the OS using my already made bootable pen drive. And there's no problem with my pen drive cause I have tried it on my friends PC and it worked normally.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you done a cold shutdown, placed the drive in a usb slot, then turned the machine on? Also while booting look for the F options. All of my computers allow me to on the fly choose what to boot with.

Comment: What BIOS version are you using?

Comment: why not use wubi?

Comment: What did you use in creating the bootable USB? Try UnetBootin. If it still fails to boot, try another USB. Or check if your BIOS can really boot with a USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check your BIOS bootscreen to see if there's an option to boot from your USB drive *right now*. For example, for me it's usually been F12. If there is such a menu but your USB key isn't listed then your BIOS might not support booting from it.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't boot from a USB drive (and have no CD drive, which you didn't say), the methods here will probably work for you:

https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Installation/FromWindows

Answer (score 0):

Just use `wubi`, I'm doing it right now on my 2002 dell XP notebook and its so simple.

Comment: I'm not sure if this actually solves the OP's problem.

Comment: How to use `wubi`? If OP doesn't know about it for that case you should have to explain it little more. And I don't think this will resolve the problem.